# Angular SCSS color variables not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, angular, internet-explorer, sass

I have been facing issue with scss color variables. we are using angular library for color variable.those whos coming from the library they are not replacing the actual color value after bundling. my page not loading as expected in the IE11.
[Here is the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0iz9.png).

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Answer (score 1):

use [css-vars-ponyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-vars-ponyfill)

```
<!-- Latest v2.x.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/css-vars-ponyfill@2"></script>
<script>
  cssVars({
    // Options...
  });
</script>
```

Comment: using this i am able to load my variables. but my question is that angular cli will replace color codes in place of the color variables right? why in my context its not working?